# Half size breadboard problem

Tags: led, breadboard

I purchased the Raspberry Pi YouTube Workshop Kit from Buy a Pi.com a few days ago. I have a B+. But when I completed tutorial number two, *LEDs On and Off*, only the LED on the right turned on. Then I swapped the lights to see if one was burnt out and again only the one on the right turned on. Then I swapped resistors (yes, I'm using the correct ones) and NEITHER turned on. Now nothing will do anything- no lights on, no circuits working, it's all so confusing. does anyone know what happened and how I could fix it? I can't post a picture because I only have three rep, but I added link below. I'm absolutely sure it's wired properly.

Please help me, I need to do a presentation on Friday with the board.

Thanks!

Some links you might need:
Purchase website- https://www.buyapi.ca/product/raspberry-pi-youtube-workshop-kit/

Scroll down to lesson two. The video and wiring diagram are there.
I'd give the links but I need 10 rep.

Comment: could you upload a picture of the set up or include some links relating to your project? Sounds like you have wired up the breadboard wrong have not correctly configured the GPIO

Comment: I'm closing this for now because if you seriously want help, you have to turn this into a question where the answer is not just, "I guess you broke it or something".  Simply saying, "I did everything right but it doesn't work" is pointless. You did not even include a link to the tutorial you refer to.  You are putting the onus on others, who will not be bothered because it is not their problem. You need to think about providing a useful amount of information including, as Darth says, a picture of the situation.  *If* you did something wrong, we need information that would allow us to see that.

Comment: [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: Because you got burned on the "enough rep for an image" (which I think is stupid too, but was not fully aware of), I'll re-open this.  I doubt you are going to get much of a response, though, for reasons I've already cited -- lack of a picture was not the only one.

Comment: Hmmph -- I really thought I reopened this yesturday.  Sorry about that.  The first time I used LEDs I burned a few out without knowing it (or they came as duds).  You can test them with some multimeters, or obviously if you have at least one working by swapping it out.  Note that rearranging stuff connected to the GPIOs with the pi running *can* lead to undefined behavior, lol.   You need to make sure you understand what's up and until then, always remove the power before you do stuff.

Comment: In [other news](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258875/which-se-sites-require-10-reputation-points-to-post-images/258876?noredirect=1#comment843771_258876), I think you jumped the gun *assuming* you could not post an image here with no rep.  I did not know for sure and assumed you had tried -- but now I am thinking you based that on a previous experience at S.U. or Mathematics?

Comment: Thanks again @goldilocks. Sorry about that. I thought it was a standard policy kind of thing. I'm pretty sure I disconnected the power- would running  2_off.py which tuns off the lights be fine?

Comment: As long as you have the connections as they are in that wiring diagram you can't do any harm.  Note that LED's aren't reversible -- they have a positive and a negative lead, *usually* the long one is positive but it can (supposedly) be backward.  To double check you have to look at the top, inside the plastic (if you search "led polarity" you'll find guides to that).   Worst comes to worst, some consumer electronics stores -- e.g. "The Source", I think you are in Canada ;) -- sell little bags of LEDs for $5.  I don't think resistors would be prone to damage/failure in this context.